# angularjs how set right scope for function?

Tags: angularjs

have this ng-repeat

```
<li class="tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-portlet" ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <div>
        <span class="tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-portlet-toggler" ng-click="tatbppTogler()">{{{tatbppt}}}</span>
        <span class="tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-portlet-number">{{question.id}}</span>
        {{question.text}}
    </div>
    <div class="tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-portlet-options" ng-show="showTatbppo">
        ...
    </div>
</li>
```

I want, for click in "tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-portlet-toggler" change visibility "tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-portlet-options" and change text in "tmmenu-admin-tabs-builder-panel-portlet-toggler".
And i write this code for get result:

```
$scope.tatbppTogler = function(){
        $scope.showTatbppo = !$scope.showTatbppo;
        if($scope.showTatbppo){
            $scope.tatbppt = "-";
        }else{
            $scope.tatbppt = "+";
        }
    }
```

It's works, but changed dom in all "Li", how changed only current (where user click) "li"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1 way

you can pass **this** in   `ng-click="tatbppTogler(this)"` and then in function manipulate with **this**

### 2 way

you can create custom directive and apply it to your li element and then on this directive bind click to element and listen , and on click function will be triggered your listener and you will have access on this element

Comment: In 1 way "this" work like scope? else its right 1 way easy, but it is a good decision?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
<li class=portlet" ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <div>
       <span class="toggler" ng-click="showTatbppo=!showTatbppo">{{showTatbppo ? "+" : "-" }}</span>
    <span class="number">{{question.id}}</span>
    {{question.text}}
</div>
<div class="options" ng-show="showTatbppo">
    ...
</div>
</li>
```

Working fiddle, with this concept: 
http://jsfiddle.net/x1nguaxj/

btw. You have very-very-very long css class names :)

Comment: All time problem invent class names)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute id for each question and then change based on the id of the question you clicked

Comment: I try, tatbppTogler(question.id) and showTatbppo[question.id] and $scope.showTatbppo[id] = !$scope.showTatbppo[id], but take error $scope.showTatbppo not defined. I newbie in angular and don't how debug this error.

Comment: you can debug angular with your browser element inspector, in chrome just right click the page and inspect element, you can then set breakpoints etc

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you'd take a look at `$index`. From the angularjs [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

Using this, you can clearly determine the certain div that was clicked on.